# Is there a clever way to use a picture as a list bullet and then draw something on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Because I basically want to use a profile picture as a list bullet (which I already accomplished by using

```
list-style-image :url("myURL");
```

in my css file).

However, I would like to draw a circle in the picture, which represents the online state of a user.

Is there a clever way to do this? Or would I have to take the long run and remove the list-bullet and then add a div I can paint onto and move it to the point where usually the list-bullet is sitting around?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give it an id/class and target it to change its url attribute

Comment: you can create a pseudo-element that changes the background-color depending on the `li` class. changing the url attribute won't work because you'd have to draw the circle in each user profile picture...

Comment: A `::before` pseudo element with `content` of some circular Unicode character might do, though you'd have to position it very carefully.

Comment: Use a different element and overlay a transparent png atop the image that's set as a background

Comment: Easier way is to remove the default list-style entirely (`none`) and use a marker with both content (the circle, \u25EF) and background-image (the profile pic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo:

```
<ul class="users">
{foreach user in users}
    <li style="background-image:url({user.image})" class="{user.online}">{user.name}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.users li{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:   contain;
  padding-left:      30px;
  list-style:        none;
  position:          relative;
  margin:            5px 0;
}


ul.users li.online:before{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:    #2d2;
  position:      absolute;
  content:       "";
  height:        10px;
  width:         10px;
  left:          -5px;
  top:           -5px;
}
```

```css
body{
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  color:#556;
  margin:0;
}


ul.users li{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:   contain;
  padding-left:      30px;
  list-style:        none;
  position:          relative;
  margin:            5px 0;
}


ul.users li.online:before{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:    #2d2;
  position:      absolute;
  content:       "";
  height:        10px;
  width:         10px;
  left:          -5px;
  top:           -5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="users">
  <li style="background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KubCT.jpg?s=24)" class="online">Stefan Schranz</li>
  <li style="background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIkv.jpg?s=24)" class="">Roko C. Buljan</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a before or after pseudo with css.  Use your background image in your li and then just add a class based on status and add some css: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEGpv/110/)

Using a background image made it easier to place something on top of the li.

*Edit: I added a better example for you

HTML:

```
<br><br>
    <ul>
        <li class="ex1"></li>
        <li class="ex2"></li>        
    </ul>
    li {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #FA6900;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }
```

CSS:

```
  li {
    background-image: url('http://www.openclipart.org/people/lemmling/lemmling_Ladybug.svg');
    background-size: 5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li.ex1:after {
    content: '\d5';
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}

li.ex2:after {
    content: '\d7';
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
```